# What is the difference between gcloud alpha commands and gcloud beta commands?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a one question aboud gcloud (google-cloud-sdk).

I have found a gcloud components to using interavtive shell of google cloud.

using like this command

`[hostname]# gcloud components list`

and I found a results

```
│ Installed │ gcloud Alpha Commands│ alpha  │   < 1 MiB │
│ Installed | gcloud Beta Commands │ beta   │   < 1 MiB │
```

In google cloud (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/interactive-gcloud), shows a 'gcloud Alpha Commands' but not exist 'gcloud Beta Commands'.

What is the difference between alpha commands and beta commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the lifecycle.

Alpha means that the feature is typically not ready for production and might still be actively developed.

Beta on the other hand is normally a completed feature, that is being tested to be production ready.

For more info: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)

Answer (score 1):

In context of Google Cloud, these release stages are described on their [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/products#section-22) product website.

> Alpha: ... The alpha phase usually lasts six months.
>
> Beta: ... The average beta phase lasts about six months.

I recommend, to learn more about this you should read from the source. :)