# Google Cloud (GCP) Setting up Multi-cluster Ingress - Error for gcloud command "gcloud alpha container hub ingress enable \ --config-membership"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-anthos

I am trying to setup Multi-cluster Ingress in GCP, following the steps at the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress-setup#using-gcloud-init).

When I try to setup config cluster using following command, it's giving me error -

```
$ gcloud alpha container hub ingress enable \
       --config-membership=projects/myproject/locations/global/memberships/gke-us
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container.hub.ingress.enable) INVALID_ARGUMENT: InvalidValueError for field config_membership:
> Membership
> "projects/myproject/locations/global/memberships/projects/myproject/locations/global/memberships/gke-us"
> does not exist

When I run `kubectl config get-contexts`, I can see the gke-us exists.

```
> $ gcloud container hub memberships list.      
NAME    EXTERNAL_ID
> gke-us  2b7924f5-c55e-485f-959b-9048b0920713 
> gke-eu  9ed69091-56b7-44c0-af49-2ccf817c5fcf
```

I have done this setup earlier few times and never faced this issue but suddenly it has started coming.

Comment: Just wondering if you have tried to get the output from running the $ gcloud command without [alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853286/what-is-the-difference-between-gcloud-alpha-commands-and-gcloud-beta-commands)

Comment: Can you post the output of `gcloud container hub memberships list` ?

Comment: @GariSingh - added output above

Comment: Still looking into this, but are you sure your project_id is actually `myproject`?
You might also want to try `gcloud container hub memberships list --uri` as it should output the URIs for each member.

Comment: i changed it here.. I am using the right project name.

Comment: the output seems to be repeating ```"projects/myproject/locations/global/memberships/projects/ myproject/locations/global /memberships/gke-us``` Please could you confirm is not a copy paste error typo.